# Jquery find next index

Tags: jquery, indexing

What is the correct way to find the index of elements.  I am using a `div` that appends a new div into a container and I must "have" a new ID based on the index - this allows for easy indexing on a delete function later. i.e. I can just run a `each function` to update the id's

this is my code: - I want to find the index of class `.pollq` when `#addoption` is clicked

```
$('#addoption').live('click',function(){
    var index = index('.pollq');

    alert(index);   

    $(this).parent('form').append('<br /><label for="">Option #'+($('.pollq').length+1)+'</label><input type="text" id="polloption'+($('.pollq').length+1)+'" class="pollq generate" />');

    $('#pollpreview').append('<br /><input type="radio"><span class="polloption'+($('.pollq').length)+'">Options polloption'+($('.pollq').length)+'</span>');

});
```

Comment: if you can provide some html, please do.

Comment: @Reigel - sorry missed your comment. the html is very easy just 2 "container" divs - the form & #pollpreview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#addoption').live('click',function(){
    var i = $(this).parent('form').find('.pollq').length;
    var id = "polloption"+i;

    $(this).parent('form').append(
        '<br /><label for="'+id+'">Option #'+i+'</label><input type="text" id="'+id+'" class="pollq generate" />'
    );

    // note that this should be a <label>, too
    $('#pollpreview').append(
        '<br /><input type="radio"><span class="'+id+'">Options '+id+'</span>
    ');
});
```

Comment: yep - I had something like this earlier (which worked) I was just hoping to use "index" rather than length therefore making reindexing easier on a delete function - such is life

Comment: @Russell: Why do you want to re-index when you delete elements? This should not be necessary...

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the index of an element with the class "pollq", relative to its container:

```
var index = $('.pollq').index();
```

Is that what you wanted?

i.e. index would be "2" in the following example:

```
<div>
    <div class="something"></div>
    <div class="something-else"></div>
    <div class="pollq"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @David - that is what I thought but it is giving me "silly" numbers i.e. always an index of 7 yet there are only 2 "static" pollq's - strange?

Comment: `$('.something')` does not work "relative to the container". It's document-wide.

Comment: @Tomalak: yes, but `index` is relative to the container

Comment: @Russell: if you have two elements of class "pollq" it will always return the index of the first, relative to *its* container, which may well be 7. If you want to know how *many* elements of class "pollq" there are, you should use `$('.pollq').length`

Comment: @David - thanks for last comment got it now, shame as  I was just hoping to use "index" rather than length therefore making reindexing easier on a delete function

Comment: @Russell: Well, the thing is, `$('.pollq')` will give you a list of items. How do you single out the one having the index you want? If you *have* an object, and want to know where it is in a collection you could do `$.inArray(thisPollQ, $('.pollq'))`. Note that `thisPollQ` needs to be a DOM node. If it's a jQuery object, use `thisPollQ[0]`. If you're *iterating* over a list of `.pollq` objects, and want to know at what index the *current* one is, then you can accept that as a parameter in your iterator: `$('.pollq').each(function(index) { ... });`